# Using Python with Google Maps and avoid coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps

I want to get the route between 2 points using google maps api but I want also avoid some coordinates between them.

I have been investigating this feature but I do not know if it is possible to get this done. See these threads:

[Is there a way to avoid a specific road or coordinate in Google Directions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272322/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-a-specific-road-or-coordinate-in-google-directions)

[Avoid some coordinates in routes using Google Directions API Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479796/avoid-some-coordinates-in-routes-using-google-directions-api-android)

Anyone know if it is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid feature has been introduced in Google Maps Distance Matrix API, however it can only be used to avoid Tolls, Highways, Ferries, and Indoor.

you can check this on its documentation page.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

This feature is pretty popular and has been formerly requested in Google Issue Tracker. If you really need it you can go ahead and support it by starring it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816642